# Are a blinded creature's squares as hard to Tumble through as a sighted creature's?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, movement, opportunity-attack, blind

One of the [Tumble](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#tumble) skill's skill uses is

> Tumble at one-half speed **through an area occupied by an enemy** (over, under, or around the opponent) as part of normal movement, provoking no attacks of opportunity while doing so. Failure means you stop before entering the enemy-occupied area and provoke an attack of opportunity from that enemy. Check separately for each opponent. Each additional enemy after the first adds +2 to the Tumble DC. (*Player's Handbook* 84)

(Emphasis mine.) The DC for this skill use is typically 25. However, a typical creature that's [blinded](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#blinded) can't make attacks of opportunity, its foes having, effectively, [total concealment](http://dndsrd.net/combatModifiers.html#total-concealment) with regards to the creature. Is this use of the Tumble skill under such circumstances addressed somewhere? That is, is the Tumble skill check's DC the same to get through a blinded foe's square(s) as it is to get through the square(s) of a foe that *can* see?

---

***Note:*** The hex dragon's [glitterdust](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#glitterdust) *spell blinded [the equiceph](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109075/8610) that was blocking the passage. The [speedy scout](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/88648/8610) wanted to jam through the blinded equiceph's space to attack a* different *equiceph. The table was momentarily dumbfounded, thinking the equiceph's blindness should have at least* some *impact on this Tumble skill use. I ruled that it was, instead, a Tumble skill check (DC 15) to get through the blinded equiceph's square, but now I'm wondering if this is a house rule that should stand or if the rules actually address this situation.*

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well, I guess I shouldn't be surprised that I didn't see the `blind` tag.

Comment: Ha! Actually, I didn't know either. I was actually expecting it to not exist and typed it out of curiosity, and even when it showed up I expected it to synonym to [[tag:conditions]]…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You still need to roll** but you won't take the AOO if you fail. But you will stop moving.

> [You can’t move through a square occupied by an opponent, unless the opponent is helpless.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/movementPositionAndDistance.htm)

A blinded opponent is not helpless, so you must tumble past.